# How to be protected against power outages when writing app state to disk

Tags: c#, windows, io, filesystems, ntfs

I have an application state which should be stored to a file. Each time it makes a new file with different name (like "data.bin.new") and then after writing deletes the original "data.bin" and renames "data.bin.new". Recently I had a power surgery and the data file was corrupted. How it could happened and how to protect against it?

```
    public void SaveData()
    {
        string newName = _dataFile + ".new";
        string bckName = _dataFile + ".bck";
        string normalName = _dataFile;

        using (var f = File.Create(newName))
        {
            f.SetLength(0);
            AqlaSerializer.Serializer.Serialize(f, V);
        }

        var test = LoadData(newName);
        if (!typeof(T).IsValueType && ReferenceEquals(test, null)) throw new Exception("Can't load what's been saved");

        if (File.Exists(bckName)) File.Delete(bckName);
        if (File.Exists(normalName)) File.Move(normalName, bckName);
        File.Move(newName, normalName);
    }
```

Comment: get a UPS for your computer

Comment: Totally preventing corruption with high level code is really difficult if even possible, but I wish to give you an hint. The last line of your code renames the new file in the working file. If something really bad happend in this code you will have the new file still hanging around in that folder. When you read the configuration back check if the new file exists. You will know that something has not gone as expected. This will not remove the possibility of data corruption but should make a crash when you read the data less probable. Of course @MickyD  is right.

Comment: You cannot solve a hardware problem with software.